# Ubuntu 14.04: reset xrandr config

Tags: 14.04, xrandr

I did a wrong setting with xrandr (wrong use of --scale parameter) and now my Ubuntu 14.04 freeze after unity login screen

I tried to remove (from recovery shell) *~/.config/monitors.xml*
and set `xrandr --output VGA1 --mode 800x600` on *~/xprofile*

but I can't reset this config.

How can I restore/put default my display settings?

Answer (score 5):

Try resetting your display typing:

```
xrandr -s 0
```

If -as you say- you can't login via your GUI, try to go to a virtual terminal with Ctrl-Alt-F1, login there, and try with these commands:

```
export DISPLAY=:0
xrandr -s 0
```

You can even do this over the network through SSH.

Comment: Some more detail on this would have been nice. It didn't reset my primary monitor as I'd hoped, but it did turn off both my other displays making it that much more obnoxious to try to fix on the one monitor I was already having display problems on.